# My images got layers even when it has not been edited it in an imaging software. why ? possible explanations

Tags: adobe-photoshop, inkscape, layers, images

im having trouble with my unedited images opening as layers.

im working with a scientific image. i have never edited this image on photoshop. i have opened this image on inkscape and have once tried to convert the TIFF file to an EMF format on my MAC computer.

now when i open my image in photoshop, for some reason, this  images have got some other image as a layer.  Why does it happen ? can someone give an explanation?

Comment: Hi Sheena and welcome to GDSE. When unexplainable things happen what usually helps is to show what you're talking about

Comment: This is quite difficult to answer without access to the file, but yes, some TIF images can indeed have layers.  The format does support layers.

Comment: What's the "other image" - is it a different image entirely or just a duplicate of the original image? --*guessing* your attempt to covert to EMF caused some alteration to the file.